# Undefined control sequence error with \includegraphics

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\date{25/07/2016}

\begin{document}

4541

\includegraphics[scale = 1]{poi.eps}

\end{document}
```

It gives error as below

```
./test1.tex:9:Undefined control sequence\includegraphics
```

Comment: Hello! although I didn't have poi.eps, I was able to compile your document without any errors after substituting a file I had.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This works fine for me (as it should). Can you add the complete contents of the `.log` file to your post?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Is that the first error that you see or do you see an error that says that graphicx isn't loading?

Answer (score 0):

Not all compilers support .eps files.  Try and substitute your file for a .pdf or .jpg and see if you still get the error – if you don't you need to convert your image.

Comment: Welcome, the error is not related to the file format.